How to calculate the sum of each type of individuals (adult_male, adult_female, adult_unknown_sex, juvenile_male, etc) grouped by cruise?

I have this dataset,and I want to calculate how many individuals of each type were collected in each cruise. I have 54 cruises and in each cruise, different jars were collected. What i did is:
Tot_Vol <- tspin2 %>% 
  group_by(Cruise) %>% 
  summarize(Tot_Vol = sum(unique(Volume_m3)))

and I found the tot volume of all jars for each cruise. Now I am trying to calculate the tot num of individuals for each type.
I tried:
tspin2 %>% 
  group_by(Cruise) %>% 
  summarize(Tot_Ind = sum(unique(Type), 8))

but it didn't work. Any idea? Thanks a lot!!!

First pivot your data into long format so that you have, for example, columns for Cruise, AgreGroup, Sex and any other variables you need.  Your life will be much easier in the long run.  Then read the link that @LTyrone has given you.

In particular, the answer by @LMc from the above link is the most up-to-date. As of dplyr 1.1.0, you no longer need to use a separate group_by() statement. You just use .by = inside summarise() instead.
